# How to allow to enter text longer than width of MFC ComboBox

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, combobox

If the text is longer than the width of an MFC ComboBox, it stops accepting new characters.
If paste long text to an MFC ComboBox, the remaining part (longer than displayable) are trimmed.

How to allow full text be entered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Combobox control has a property `'auto'` that automatically scrolls text that is too long to fit. By default it's false. Set it to true to enable this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my day :)

Comment: Thank you very much!
That flag is actually called **CBS_AUTOHSCROLL** but Visual Studio Editor calls it **auto**